# Why does this code does not work on Pie and later?

Tags: android

I tried this code, it works fine on Android 8, but when I try to run applications on Android 9 it does not work and shows:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

Here is the code:

```
@Override
 protected void onPostExecute(String massage) {

     Type type = new TypeToken < ArrayList < HashMap < String, String >>> () {}.getType();

     Gson gson = new Gson();

     ArrayList < HashMap < String, String >> arr = gson.fromJson(massage, type);



     for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
         if (!Objects.equals(arr.get(i).get("region"), city)) {
             arr.get(i).clear();
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Likely the input you're passing to this code is different - trying to parse something that is not json as json.

Comment: To that end, use a debugger or `Log` statements to look at the value of `message`.

Comment: but why does it work on android 8 and on android 9 not

Comment: @MichaelGhevondyan This is a bug that occurs when you try to pass in badly formed JSON to GSON.  It won't work on either OS with that input.  Instead, try to figure out why you have different input on the 2 OSes and how to fix the bad one.

Comment: can you tell me how to find out if it’s not difficult for you, I’m just new to android